# Как мне вернуть результат из функции использующую axios с обещанием

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, асинхронность, promise

Есть допустим функция в которой axios запрос и потом мне нужно из этой функции вернуть результат запроса. Как это сделать - не ясно. Т.е. внутри функции я могу взаимодействовать с данными погружаясь в функции then или ожидать через await, но это не даёт нужного результата. Интересует возможно ли вообще такое сделать?

Пример функции:

```
static get(url) {
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("url", url);
  
  let result;
  
  axios.post("php/get.php", fd).then((response) => {
    result = response.data;
  });

  return result; // как подождать ответа?
}
```

Comment: Как вы не понимаете, что асинхронная операция - это операция которая всегда останется асинхронной. Сложность в том, что нужно ждать. А ждать умеют ну по видимому только промисы - микротаски и таймауты - макротаски.

Comment: По идеи, логично, что в данном случае вы можете получить promise. Тогда ```const promise = axios.post("php/get.php", fd).then((response) => response.data;
  });```  Если axios  действительно может вернуть promise, как  feth, ибо я с ним не на ты. Тогда внутри функции вам доступен promise, однако он не доступен где-то еще, потому, что мы либо выполняем все сразу, делая логическую цепочку, либо ничего не выполняем.

Comment: Но если axios, это promise, тогда мы можем снова его вернуть и где-то ниже обращаться к результату get(url).then((то, что вернул promise, как  resolve) => resolve) Однако помните, что это асинхронные действия и цепочка должна идти через  then. Вы можете сохранить цепочку в другую переменную/функцию

Comment: Если axios  не вернул promise, оберните сам axios  в promise

Comment: Получается никак так нельзя сделать :(
Единственный вариант как я понимаю - возвращать promise и с ним работать.

Comment: Все, что вы можете сделать, это супер удобный синтаксис  обработав ошибки  try,cath и ждать через  await, а приставка async - это автоматический оборот в promise.  Для вас это обертка, но за кулисами бейбел все очень умно переделает на привычные  then. Я уже выше писал, не нравятся супер крутые микротаски, используйте макротаски.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const oldPromise = new Promise((res) => {
  //Сейчас этот код работает синхронно и ничего не ждет внутри.
  const a = 1;
  const b = 1;
  res(a + b);
});

//Мы вроде получили результат, но нет!
console.log(oldPromise);

//Нам необходимо ждать
const newPromise = oldPromise.then((answer) => { 
  console.log(answer, 'теперь мы точно получили результат'); 
  return answer + 100
}
);

//Мы можем соеденять новые цепочки, однако это не будет иметь ничего с прошлой.
oldPromise
  .then((answer) => answer + 1)
  .then((oldConsole) =>
    console.log(oldConsole, 'обратите внимания, это другая цепочка')
  );
  
//Мы все еще работаем с oldPromise. 
newPromise.then(data => console.log(data, 'это наш oldPromise'))
```

Comment: Кстати вам "на подумать", почему если код читается сверху вниз, мы когда работаем с newPromise, он вызывается второй, хотя в коде по счету он третий, а новый промис оказался на верху.

Comment: потому что во втором дважды then и т.к. оно ассинхронно то третий заканчиваеться быстрее второго?

Comment: В каком-то смысле да, но тут стоит разбираться в том, что микротаски это не просто быстрые операции, а все операции за цикл. У вас цепочка  then не прерывная, по этому пишите хоть выше, хоть ниже, пока цепочка не закончится, другого микротаска не будет либо микротаск в микротаске, как вариант.